# Bootstrap close button doesnt show

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I inject the alert dynamically:

```
$('#'+this.id).append('<div id="alert" class="alert alert-success alert-  dismissible" style="display:none;width:50%;" role="alert">'+  
      '<button id="alertclosebutton" type="button" class="close" data-  dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>  </button></div>');
```

when i get an ajax return i show the alert:

```
$('#alert').css("display", "block");
$('#alert').text(realmsg);
```

I cannot make the close button show.. I want it to be with display none not   hidden to save space on the screen..

Comment: in your question, the `alert-dismissible` has a space in it ...  Can we assume it's a typo when creating the question ?  Otherwise, you might have your answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#alert').text(realmsg);
```

This statement removes the inside button and added the message ,
If its right? then you can add one div for your message like below.

```
<div id="alert" ... >
  <div class="messagediv">your message area</div>
  <button id="alertclosebutton" ../>
</div>

$('#alert').find('.messagediv').text(realmsg);
```